# Can't delete partitions after attempting BOOTCAMP on my iMac 5k

Tags: imac, bootcamp, core-storage

I recently tried to install a bootcamp instance of Win 7. The install failed for some reason. This left me with a partition that I can not access via Disk Utility [image]

If you notice..the +- can not be selected and hence I can't delete the partition and recover the space on my drive

I tried to follow the instructions posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168781/can-not-delete-free-space-on-imac-5k-partition-doesnt-appear-in-cs-list#new-answer?newreg=809bf4994dfe45c98b50e37bb9ce406f) by klanomath but have had no success.

It could be because I have 2 CoreStorage logical volume groups about which I have no clue as to what it is

Klanomath...can you please help me out???

diskutil list--

[image: diskutil list]

diskutil cs list--

[image: diskutil cs list]

sudo gpt -r -vv /dev/disk1--

[image]

Comment: did you try in Debug menu ?

Comment: I really dont know how to

Comment: to enable the debug menu, use terminal "defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1"

Comment: And what will this do?

Comment: not much, as the name says it is used for debugging, and to show all hidden partitions. A question to you, do you have 2 OS X versions installed ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Just running Yosemite. I transferred data from my MBP Retina to this new iMac 5k and that's about it

Comment: you see what I see and it shows 2 OS X partitions and one bootcamp.

Comment: Yes I do..sorry for the late reply. This happened when I tried to use BootCamp

Comment: Prior to installing BootCamp the disk utility showed nothing abnormal. While trying to install Windows, which never happened due to some formatting issue when I came back to DU to delete the partition I found it in this state

Comment: @klanomath thank you for helping me out. Yes I have a 50mb fibre optic connection at home. Don't have a Yosemite thumb drive though

Comment: After you have restored your computer using klanomath's instructions, do you still intend to install Windows 7?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Not until Apple comes up with a BootCamp that wont break my fusiondrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went totally wrong and your Logical Volume Group is fragmented. You have to rebuild your Fusion Drive from scratch:

**Preparation:**

- Backup "Macintosh HD" to an external drive with Time Machine
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 5 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (Yosemite).

**Rebuild Fusion Drive**

- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:
  `diskutil cs list` to get the CoreStorage listing.
- Copy the second Logical Volume Group UUID, it's the seventh listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
- Then delete the second Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVG2UUID`.
  In your case: `diskutil cs delete E0E4516A-DE3A-4B62-BE6A-855A760F5E3E`
- Copy the Logical Volume UUID it's the sixth UUID listed
- delete the Logical Volume with `diskutil cs deleteVolume LVUUID`.
  In your case: `diskutil cs deleteVolume 00CDC215-F00D-4AD4-BA78-A2B220278688`
- Copy the first Logical Volume Group UUID, it's the first listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
- Then delete the first Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID`.
  In your case: `diskutil cs delete 8FCBCB92-43CC-45A2-A058-58CAF79B93B4`
- Enter `exit` and quit 'Terminal'
- Open 'Disk Utility'. Enter 'Ignore' if you are asked to fix the drives.
- Choose your SSD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~121 GB

  Example:
  *Beware! Since I took the screenshots in a virtual machine which couldn't be booted to Internet Recovery Mode i had to create two example disks with different disk identifiers and sizes. So don't use my UUIDs and disk identifiers recreating your Fusion Drive.*

  [image: ssd]
- Choose your HDD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~3 TB

  Example:

  [image: hdd]
- Quit Disk Utility and open Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list`

  Example (your disk identifiers and sizes are different of course: Your volume SSD probably has the Identifier disk0s2 and the size 121 GB and your volume HDD probably has the Identifier disk1s2 and the size 3.0 TB):

  [image: diskutil]
- Enter `diskutil cs create "Name" IdentifierSSD IdentifierHDD`
  In your case probably `diskutil cs create "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk1s2`.

  Copy the resulting LVGUUID

  Example:

  [image: cscreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs CreateVolume LVGUUID jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%`.

  Example:

  [image: lvcreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
  Check the size of your Logical Volume. It should have the size ~3.121 TB

  Example:

  [image: diskcslist]
- Quit Terminal
- Open 'Disk Utility' and check your newly created volume for errors
- Quit 'Disk Utility'

**Restoring "Macintosh HD" from Time Machine backup** (alternatively you may reinstall OS X and migrate your users and apps - see below)

- Attach your external Time Machine backup drive or check this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162544/how-to-restore-system-from-network-drive) if you use NAS or another network share.
- Open 'Restore from Time Machine Backup'

  [image]
- Choose the appropriate Time Machine backup and restore your system
  The messages on your screen may differ slightly (different names and backup source)

  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
- Reboot to your restored system.
- Unmount and detach your Time Machine backup drive
- Open 'Terminal' and enter 'diskutil list'
- Check if your 'Recovery HD' is listed.
- If your 'Recovery HD' is missing, usually reinstalling your current system with the latest available system installer (e.g. 'Install OS X Yosemite (10.10.2)' if Yosemite is currently installed) will recreate it without loosing any data. AFAIK [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/) will NOT create a Recovery HD on CoreStorage volumes.
- After reinstalling the system with the latest available system installer open `App Store` and install the latest security fixes.

**Reinstalling Yosemite from scratch and migrating apps & data from Time Machine backup**

- Choose "Reinstall OS X"

  [image: Reinstall OS X]
- Choose "Macintosh HD" as destination disk
- after the download, installation and a restart the Setup Assistant will ask you - beyond other questions - to migrate users, apps and other data
- attach your Time Machine Backup drive and wait a few seconds
- choose "Migrate from Time Machine backup" (or something similar - i don't remember the precise message.)
- finish the migration
- start App Store.app and install the latest updates.

Comment: FYI, it isn't that the mods personally don't like extended commenting, it's that the system isn't set up for it.

Comment: @DanielLawson Ok next time i will use that as explanation ;-)