# Fusion Drive lost space after bootcamp-fail. resizeStack throws an error. What can I do?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, disk-utility, fusion-drive

I have a 2 TB Fusion Drive in a 5K iMac (Late 2015). Two days ago, I started the bootcamp assistant to create a partition for Windows 10. It got stuck (let it run 30 minutes), however, which forced me to reboot the machine. After booting, I lost 164 GB from my Fusion Drive.

I googled and found a solution, which states to boot into recovery and run `diskutil cs resizeStack <LGVID> 0g`, which I did. However, I am not able to let it resize, because it immediately throws an error. Following the error does not work either.

I also tried repairing the disk with Disk Utility which runs for a few minutes, then says everything's fine. Nothing changed of course.

[image: diskutil outputs]

Output of `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`:
[image]

Output of `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`:
[image]

What can I do now?

Comment: Please add your system version. To verify a Fusion drive use `diskutil verifyDisk diskX` with X=disk identifier of the two disk building the drive - in your case either 0 or 1 (check the physical volumes in your screenshot).

Comment: OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 (haven't upgraded to .3 just yet). If I run it with disk0 or disk1, it complains that it will delete my stuff.

Comment: Using the **verifyDisk** (instead of repairDisk!) argument deletes stuff? The proper command to resize a stack in El Capitan is a distinctive size (i.e. `diskutil cs resizeStack 25FF.... 2126g` or slightly smaller like 2125500m)

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

Comment: Sorry, misread that as `repairDisk`. Just appended two screenshots with the outputs.

Comment: Just tried `resizeStack` with a value that is not 0g. Still complains about incorrect size.

Answer (score 1):

Since I wasn't able to resize the stack and seemingly no one was able to help me, I decided to to this:

- Make an image of the Fusion Drive Volume and save it onto an external hard drive
- Delete the Fusion Drive
- Rebuild the Fusion Drive
- Install OS X to let it create the Recovery partition
- Boot OS X, run Bootcamp Assistant
- Run the Windows Installer WITH NO EXTERNAL DRIVES ATTACHED (!)
- Restore the image to the Fusion Drive
- Be happy after 10 hours of work

Not the best procedure to do but as this was the only thing that seemed to help, I did it.

For recreating the Fusion Drive I used this answer from klanomath:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168744/109455

I have a working setup with OS X El Capitan and Windows 10 now.