# Missing space on Fusion Drive (partition problem)

Tags: hard-drive, macos, partition, core-storage, fusion-drive

I know this or similar problems have been discussed, but (to be honest) I can't see the trees for the wood. 
I tried to create a partition on my fusion drive (1TB Hd + 240 MB SSD). No partition was created but afterwards the capacity of my (1.2 TB) drive had been reduced to 617 GB. With 414 GB in use, approximately 400 GB of disk space is missing.

[image]

[image]

Terminal diskutil list says:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       239.7 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS HD IMac 1              +616.6 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

and:

```
diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 53DFB831-BFCA-4552-A8F5-387F3905003A
    =========================================================
    Name:         myLogicalVolGroup
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1239058563072 B (1.2 TB)
    Free Space:   615951769600 B (616.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume A1418DDB-CB43-493F-9341-F23AE2FA7150
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 2E45A45F-D1C1-4B62-97FA-5223DD9C965E
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     239713435648 B (239.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family E3B8F7DC-C327-44A7-8BE2-2BFD2AE646EB
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          616601616384 B (616.6 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               HD IMac 1
            Volume Name:           HD IMac 1
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

Would this simply be a matter of:

```
diskutil cs resizeStack 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324 0g  (?)
```

Hope some-one can help me with this.

Comment: Ok. The plot thickens. (I know I am not supposed to write "thanks" so instead I write "Vielen Dank" for your reaction @klanomath).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) you'd have to enter a distinctive (> 0) size to execute the resizeStack command. The magical `... 0g` doesn't work anymore.

**But** in your case the `resizeStack` option is the wrong one because your Logical Volume Group already occupies almost all available space on the Fusion Drive:

Total disk space: 1240 GB
LVG size:             1239 GB
PV1 + PV2 size:   1239 GB
LV size:                  616 GB

The resizeStack option is appropriate if you want to resize the LVG and all subsequent Core Storage items (like the LV, PV and LVF).

Here you just have to expand your Logical Volume to completely fill the LVG with the following command:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID size
```

In your case that is:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324 1239g
```

If you get an error (not enough space...) choose a slightly smaller size like 1238g.

---

After further investigations one have to state that the Fusion Drive is corrupted:

Boot to Internet Recovery Mode, destroy the LVG, rebuild the Fusion Drive and restore your Time Machine backup: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168744/93229) is a how-to. Start with **'Rebuild Fusion Drive' (recommended if you have a Time Machine backup)**.

Comment: I'm messing things up. I want to post a (fairly long) answer, but don't know how to get codes in. (??) Can you help @klanomath ?

Comment: I can't. This is driving me more crazy than my faulty hard drive!

Comment: diskutil cs resizeVolume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324 1239g
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair

Comment: I have booted from an external disk.
So you advise:
    diskutil repairdisk /dev/disk0
    Repairing the partition map might erase disk0s1, proceed? (y/N)
Question: would that “destroy” not only data, but also my “fusion” drive?

Comment: @RPPeters Just use "Schijhulpprogramma" to repair your disk. Choose the Fusion Drive and hit "Repair" ("Schijf-HBDO"?). But I don't think anything will be repaired.

Comment: No, nothing repaired. Still 400 Gb missing.

Comment: @RPPeters How did this (the unallocated LVG space) happen at all? Did you try to create a second Logical Volume or install Boot Camp?

Comment: I tried to add a partition (with Schijfhulpprogramma), but after an hour or so of rattling hard drive, I restarted my iMac.....

Comment: @RPPeters That's an important hint. If you try to add a partition all the files and folders which would reside in the future partition have to be moved to lower block numbers - which may take a while. Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: Yes, I have a Time Machine backup.

Comment: @RPPeters Updated answer with a link to an earlier similar question/answer...

Comment: Please know I am a half-wit. What precisely do you mean with "destroy the LVG"? And would it be ok to boot from an external hard drive (which is a lot quicker).

Comment: @RPPeters This is described in the How-To.

Comment: So it's the section starting with "'Rebuild Fusion Drive' (recommended if you have a Time Machine backup)" ? Just to be absolutely sure....

Comment: @RPPeters Yes, but detach your backup drive before booting to Internet Recovery Mode. After rebuilding your Fusion Drive you may attach it again

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go.... And: Th....s

Comment: Ok. Thanks to @klanomath (definitely NOT thanks to Apple), my Fusion drive has been restored to its former glory. 823 GB available instead of 202 GB. Apple used to be foolproof, but those days are long gone. 
Remains the question: Can I make a new partition on my Fusion drive? (To make a Mavericks bootable partition, as El Capitan and Adobe InDesign CS 6 aren’t particularly good friends, to say the least.) I don’t think it’s possible. Or is it…..?

Comment: @RPPeters Sure! It's no problem to create a new partition. Either by shrinking the LVG and adding a new classical partition or by shrinking the LV and adding a new LV. But please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, I do it like this.
I booted in recovery mode and did what you suggested:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324 1239g
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair
```

So that was no good. Then I verified the volume:

```
diskutil verifyvolume /
Started file system verification on disk2s1 OS X Base System
Verifying file system
Checking non-journaled HFS Plus Volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume OS X Base System appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Finished file system verification on disk2s1 OS X Base System
-bash-3.2# diskutil verifyvolume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Started file system verification on disk3 HD IMac 1
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk1s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
disk1s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group 53DFB831-BFCA-4552-A8F5-387F3905003A spans 2 devices
disk0s2+disk1s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 29 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify E3B8F7DC-C327-44A7-8BE2-2BFD2AE646EB
Load and verify 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume 53DFB831-BFCA-4552-A8F5-387F3905003A appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Verifying file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume HD IMac 1 appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Finished file system verification on disk3 HD IMac 1
```

Then I tried to repair it:

```
diskutil repairvolume 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Started file system repair on disk3 HD IMac 1
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk1s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
disk1s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group 53DFB831-BFCA-4552-A8F5-387F3905003A spans 2 devices
disk0s2+disk1s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 29 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify E3B8F7DC-C327-44A7-8BE2-2BFD2AE646EB
Load and verify 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume 53DFB831-BFCA-4552-A8F5-387F3905003A appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Repairing file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
Trimming unused blocks
The volume HD IMac 1 appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required
Checking for overcommitted space in Logical Volume Group
Finished file system repair on disk3 HD IMac 1
-bash-3.2#
```

To my surprise diskutil list resulted in:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       239.7 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk2s1
/dev/disk3 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS HD IMac 1              +616.6 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Install OS X El Capitan 15.7 GB    disk4s2
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk5
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8
/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9
/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk11
/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk13
/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14
/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk15
/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk16
/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk17
```

After normal boot this is:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage myLogicalVolGroup       239.7 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS HD IMac 1              +616.6 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 7EE2FE6D-3D37-46AA-B948-52243490F324
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Install OS X El Capitan 15.7 GB    disk3s2
iMac-van-Rob-Peters-481:~ robpeters$
```

So: now I am confused (and also by the way I cannot post a reaction). I spite of all the rules I say "Thanks for your efforts so far @klanomath"

Comment: I have booted from an external disk. So you advise: diskutil repairdisk /dev/disk0 Repairing the partition map might erase disk0s1, proceed? (y/N) Question: would that “destroy” not only data, but also my “fusion” drive?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same situation. With the same error messages when trying to resize or repair the volume. None of the Disk Utility suggestions worked. In the end, followed the link provided by klanomath to rebuild the Fusion drive and restored from Time Machine backup. Back up and running in under an hour with the free disk space reclaimed.

This seems it's the only solution, on El Capitan.