# Messed up my 1TB Fusion drive on my iMac with Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-space, fusion-drive

Soooo something bad happened recently with my 1 TB Fusion drive on my 5K late 2015 iMac. I was creating a new 100 GB partition on my disk. So while the disk utility was busy scanning etc (doing its stuff). The power at my home suddenly went off so this got interrupted... When I rebooted my iMac back the disk size shows like this..

[image]

As you can see it shows 1 TB on the left side as it supposed to.. But it thinks it only got a 306.34 GB disk size after the interruption.. What happened to the other space..? In Disk Utility it only shows 1 partition.

I ran a few tests in Terminal.app with these outputs:

**diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         24.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            23.6 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +306.3 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2
                                 5C3ED08A-8DA2-405E-BFC5-E84CF864742F
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            W10PRO.VLX64.MULTi7... +3.7 GB     disk3
```

**diskutil list disk0**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

**sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0**

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=1000204886016; sectorsize=512; blocks=1953525168
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 1953525167
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1951845952      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1952255592     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953525128           7         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

**sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk1**

```
gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=24002560000; sectorsize=4096; blocks=5860000
gpt show: /dev/disk1: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Sec GPT at sector 5859999
    start     size  index  contents
        0        1         PMBR
        1        1         Pri GPT header
        2        4         Pri GPT table
        6    76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    76806  5750421      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5827227    32768      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5859995        4         Sec GPT table
  5859999        1         Sec GPT header
```

**diskutil coreStorage list**

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 367115C7-D6D1-4897-B982-A07794C9E545
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1022898851840 B (1.0 TB)
    Free Space:   715653558272 B (715.7 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume A837D2C2-A9C6-4BB1-834A-62E053EBD4C4
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     23553724416 B (23.6 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 5B84CBB0-6301-4972-BF46-0CBECCEA7922
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 4322DF83-825A-4E09-BFE7-B6B4E46E82A8
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 5C3ED08A-8DA2-405E-BFC5-E84CF864742F
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          306340560896 B (306.3 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

I will be so grateful if anyone can help me with this problem.. I need the whole 1 TB of space for work/school and personal stuff..

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show me the result of `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk2 limits`?

Comment: @Frizlab I get the following error when i enter it in the terminal: Error obtaining resizing information: disk is a Core Storage Logical Volume

Comment: Ha yes. I did not work with CoreStorage (Fusion) much… Try `diskutil coreStorage list` for me please, I think it will be much more relevant than the `diskutil list` you did ;)

Comment: @Frizlab i updated the previous image with the results of the new command results. (I can only post 2 links because of my low points).

Comment: Try `sudo diskutil cs resizeLV disk2 0`. Tell me if it works, I'll post a more complete answer you could accept, explaining why it works, what is going on, etc.

Comment: @Frizlab Getting the following error: 
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 5C3ED08A-8DA2-405E-BFC5-E84CF864742F
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair

Comment: Mmmmh… Stupid idea: did you try repair the disk? In Disk Utility, select your hard drive (at the top-most level) and click on the First Aid button.

Comment: @Emre Please post Terminal output as text and not as screenshot

Comment: @Frizlab Yes i did. It checking severals things and eventually saying "operation succesfull"

Comment: @klanomath Sorry for the inconvenient, updated my question with text output!

Comment: There goes my knowledge… I don't know why all the space is not retrieved, sorry. I encourage you to check this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168744/17436. The case is not exactly the same but you might find relevant informations. Good luck!

Comment: @Frizlab I'll look further, thanks for the effort to help me out!

Comment: Maybe try just reformatting the drive (after taking your data off of it) with Disk Utility and starting over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually made a call with Apple support. They asked me to use the option first aid in Disk Utility, this didn't help. They then asked me to reboot my iMac in recovery mode and do the same thing again. This also didn't help.

After these two options to repair my partition, they asked me to back-up whole drive and reinstall OSX. They told me that this would definitely work because the hard drive was a fusion drive, part mechanic and part ssd.. Can't remember the exact details on why this would work thought... But i reinstalled my whole OSX and got my 1TB back. :).