# Disk space given back to Mac HD after removing partition, but is not usable

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, filesystem

This looks similar to some other related questions here, but has some meaningful differences. I thought it was worth a separate question for that reason.

Like others I had an error while installing Windows 10 with Bootcamp. I had the error where you select the `BOOTCAMP`drive and then click "Format," and then the disk is renamed to "Disk 0s5" (or close to that, if I remember correctly) and there is an error when you select it to install Windows 10.

I then followed the many instructions and exited Boot Camp Assistant, delete the recently created partition, and then started to go through the process again. I went back into Boot Camp Assistant and restored the HD to all being for Mac OSX. There was an error during the process. It said it failed, but the Mac HD then said 839 GB again like it should say. However, the 175 GB I had allocated for Windows in the partition, out of the 839, were not available. So when I go to set up the partition again I only have a total of 60 GB available instead of the 235 GB available like it should say after freeing up the former partition. So the 175 I used for the partition is back on the main disk, but I can't use it for anything, and am not sure how to free it up.

This is the print out of `diskutil cs list`:

```
<my-imac:>~ <my-account-name>$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 37905FD6-6AA8-4E49-BB1E-B19031E8101E
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         838904774656 B (838.9 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 923BC4E2-174B-4C6E-B604-72C4A7263521
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     23553724416 B (23.6 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 7F30C1AF-0F14-4F43-9AF0-6058373887DA
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     815351050240 B (815.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 74B7428F-8D10-4BB8-87D3-19B8F73C2844
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume F3D44897-0134-4C19-871A-72E258AECDA8
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          837958688768 B (838.0 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

When I run [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) it also does not show the 175 GB that I should have reclaimed after deleting the partition as being available. It says I only have 60 GB available out of the 839 GB. 
[image: daisy-disk-printout]

[image: disk-utility-view]

Since daisydisk agrees with the `cs list` how can I add ~175 GB to get my fusion drive back to 1 TB total capacity?

Comment: `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` returns no snapshots. Refer to my comment .  I did that pruning before installing Windows 10 and doing the partition. From everything I can tell, the storage space from the partition, that should have been made available after deleting the partition, is somehow not usable now. The time that I freed up the 230 GB, to then making the partition, and then deleting the partition was a few hours. When the 175 partition was deleted the 175 showed up on the main Mac HD, but was not available.

Comment: Have you tried the command `diskutil cs resizeStack F3D44897-0134-4C19-871A-72E258AECDA8 0`?

Comment: cool. I’ll delete my comments - sorry it wasn’t what I expected.

Comment: @DavidAnderson before I do that, is this about resizing? Because the disk shows the right size as the total size, it just doesn't let me use it for some reason. I read through the other "System space taking up all my storage" and other related questions and did that pruning. That is what made the 230 GB available for creating the original partition. But since deleting the partition, it isn't available. I want to make sure that command you gave me would still apply before running it. Will it add partition space back to HD (already done), or make that space usable?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just added the DaisyDisk view to the original post for extra detail. You can see it says 64.7 GB free. I don't understand why the 175 GB from the partition deletion is not available.

Comment: `Have you tried the command diskutil cs resizeStack F3D44897-0134-4C19-871A-72E258AECDA8 0`...trying this now

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just decided to run your command to test it out (without knowing the fine details of how it would operate, because I had a backup and could live dangerously) and it worked! You are amazing! Can I mark your comment as the answer? I don't see that option.

Comment: Well, that answer has been posted here a Ask Different more times that I can remember.

Comment: If you want you can give an upvote to the first answer that I can find where the command is referenced: [Can't create partition on free space with Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144010/cant-create-partition-on-free-space-with-disk-utility)

Answer (score 1):

As [DavidAndersen noted in his above comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361000/disk-space-given-back-to-mac-hd-after-removing-partition-but-is-not-usable#comment478280_361000), this was me needing to resize the Stack. In hindsight, that should have been more obvious to me as 839 was not the full size of the TB disk. After issuing the `diskutil cs resizeStack F3D44897-0134-4C19-871A-72E258AECDA8 0` command the last volume is at 1 TB.

```
    +-> Logical Volume Family 74B7428F-8D10-4BB8-87D3-19B8F73C2844
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume F3D44897-0134-4C19-871A-72E258AECDA8
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1021952655360 B (1.0 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```